# LogisticRegression documentation, penalty contradictions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working through a lesson that uses LogisticRegression, and I see differences in the code usage and the documentation for the method.

I am asking if this is a mistake in the documentation, or if something is going on that I am missing.

The lesson was using the ‘lbfgs’ solver with penalty='none'. (The data set does not matter, it is how the method is invoked.)

```
lr = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', penalty='none', random_state=2)
```

- The code throws an error, as only 'l1' and 'l2' are acceptable options for penalty, with the 'lbfgs' solver.
- On the web page, it states that 'lbfgs' supports L2 or none (no regularization).
- On the web page under "parameters", it states that 'lbfgs' only supports L2 penalties.

I am using a jupyter notebook with scikit-learn 0.20.2.

The documentation refers to the web page:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: I'm not getting any error on scikit-learn 0.23.2. Try updating and check again?

Comment: I agree with you. With scikit-learn 0.22.2 or 0.23.2, the code does not complain about penalty=none. It seems like the lesson writer was using a different platform when they were testing their examples.

It is still the case that the documentation for the method on the web page is confusing, and not consistent. Makes it harder to know the right thing to do.